# How to connect to an internal Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to a Kafka cluster.

The test command is:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 59.221.101.29:19092 --topic demo_topic
```

I can access the public static IP and the port via `telnet`. However, the connection exception is:

```
[2020-03-03 16:53:53,784] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-11138-1, groupId=console-consumer-11138] Connection to node 1 (/10.0.0.98:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-03-03 16:56:01,015] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-11138-1, groupId=console-consumer-11138] Connection to node 2 (/10.0.0.99:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-03-03 16:58:08,248] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-11138-1, groupId=console-consumer-11138] Connection to node 3 (/10.0.0.17:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Both the IP and port change. It seems there is a mapping between the public IP I connect to and the internal IP of the Kafka cluster.

How to address this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you try "--bootstrap-servers" with a trailing **s** in your command? Usually the bootstrap-servers is a list of servers, hence, the naming.

Comment: Hi @mike Thanks for your reply. I have tried the command you just mentioned but it returns `bootstrap-servers is not a recognized option`

Comment: Is your port correct? default port is 9092 and not 19092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is very similar to this:

[image]

As a result, to access to Kafka cluster you have to access address which is specified by `advertised.listeners` (10.0.0.98:9092, 10.0.0.99:9092, 10.0.0.17:9092 in your case).

Reference for image: https://www.udemy.com/course/kafka-cluster-setup/

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting back is the returned advertised listeners defined on each broker

Bootstrapping only requires one address but it will return the full list of known addresses depending on the port you've connected to.

That being said, you need to communicate with your cluster administrator to figure out which networks are allowed to access your Kafka cluster